# cypher pagination total result count

Tags: pagination, cypher

I have a monstrosity of a cypher query and I need to paginate the results of it. What I am trying to do is to get the total number of results before limit is done.

Here is my test graph: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=6hq9tj

I tried to use **count(o)** in all parts of the query but I always get the same result: '**total_count: 1**'. Like in here: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=konr7. The result what I am trying to get should be: '**total_count: 6**'.

I always could make an another query just to count the results but it makes no sense to execute two queries.

Please can any one help me one this? Thanks!

Comment: Yup, it gets even more interesting if you try doing ```MATCH x:Label WITH count(*) AS total``` before and carry your ```total``` through using ```WITH```. Almost works, but if ever your offset is out of range in your query, it won't return anything, no ```total```, rather horrible.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
MATCH (o:Brand)
WITH o
ORDER BY o.name 
WITH collect({uuid:o.uuid, name:o.name}) AS brands, COUNT(distinct o.uuid) AS total
UNWIND brands AS brand_row
WITH total, brand_row
SKIP 5
LIMIT 5
RETURN COLLECT(brand_row) AS brands, total;
```

> Note: this is untested, something similar worked for me. Also, not sure how performant it is.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've gotten this to work is by defining the query twice, I'm not sure though what the impact is on performance, I would guess or hope it was cached the first time. Be warned: This is not a real solution as my comment above to the question states, if you use an offset out of range, nothing is returned!

```
// first query only to get count
MATCH (x:Brand)
WITH count(*) as total
// query again to get results  :(
MATCH (o:Brand)
WITH total, o
ORDER BY o.name SKIP 5 LIMIT 5
WITH total, collect({uuid:o.uuid, name:o.name}) AS brands
RETURN {total:total, brands:brands}
```

**If anyone comes up with a better solution, I as well would love to see it, spent enough time trying to get this to work properly.**

---

Slightly better solution that can handle offset out of range...

```
// first query to get results
MATCH (o:Brand)
WITH o
ORDER BY o.name SKIP 5 LIMIT 5
WITH collect({uuid:o.uuid, name:o.name}) AS brands
// then query again to get count
MATCH (x:Brand)
WITH brands, count(*) as total
RETURN {total:total, brands:brands}
```

**But it's still two queries and isn't a valid answer to the original question**

Comment: And I thought SQL Server sucks in paging.